# force is generally a function of $\mathbf{r}(t)$, $\mathbf{v}(t)$ and $t$

Tags: calculus

> Force is generally a function of $\mathbf{r}(t)$, $\mathbf{v}(t)$  and $t$. $$1-)\begin{cases}
> \mathbf F: \mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R \  \rightarrow \mathbb R^3\\
> (\mathbf r, \mathbf v, t) \longmapsto \mathbf F(\mathbf r,\mathbf v,t)
> \end{cases}$$

But I do't understand it . Because function from $\mathbb{R^7}$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ I don't know how is that .

---

Can we conclude that $\mathbf F(\mathbf r(t),\mathbf v(t),t)=\mathbf F(t)$ ??
Notice that : 
$$\begin{cases}
\mathbf r: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^3\\
t \longmapsto \mathbf r(t)
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\mathbf v: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^3\\
t \longmapsto \mathbf v(t)
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Force is a *vector* : thus it has $3$ component, i.e. it can be identified with a *triple* of real numbers, i.e. a point in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: The same for *position* $r$ and *velocity* $v$.

Comment: Thus: $r (3) + v (3) + t = 7$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA $\mathbf r  ,\mathbf v $ are vector .

Comment: Exactly; thus, they have $3$ components each : $3+3+1=7$ and $\mathbf F : \mathbb R^7 \to \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: See e.g. Emmanuele DiBenedetto, [Classical Mechanics : Theory and Mathematical Modeling](https://books.google.it/books?id=imrm2aOs9_8C&pg=PA57), Birkhauser (2011), page 57 : "A force $\mathbf F$ acting on $\{ P;m \}$ is given through a smooth vector-valued function $(P, \dot P ; t) \to \mathbf F (P, \dot P ; t) = (F_1(x, \dot x; t), F_2(x, \dot x ; t), F_3(x, \dot x ; t))$
 defined in a region of $\mathbb R^7$ with values in $\mathbb R^3$."

Comment: I find it a bit confusing myself. 

$m\frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2}=-b\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}-k\vec{x}$

The force is a linear combination of position and velocity. The velocity is a time derivative of position.

So it seems like all you really need to find your $\vec{F}$ is your values in $R^3 \times R=R^4$. The expansion to R^7, while perhaps valid,  seems to offer redundancies.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a world where the sun is moving rapidly in our chosen coordinate system and has a huge current loop around the equator.  The earth has a huge negative charge and is moving in the gravitational and magnetic fields of the sun.  At any time $t$ we need  $\mathbf r, \mathbf v, t$ to compute the force on the earth.  That is seven real numbers, three for each vector and one for the time, so the domain of the force function is $\Bbb R^7$.  It is not a geometric space as the coordinates have different meaning and we can't rotate among them freely, but it still has the structure of $\Bbb R^7$.  We can take any point in the space and use the function to get the force.  The force is a vector, so it has three components.  This is the real physical input to the problem-the law that gives us the force on the earth.

Now we can use Newton's laws to integrate the differential equation and find $\mathbf v(t), \mathbf r(t)$.  Having done that, we can plug into $\mathbf F(\mathbf r,\mathbf v,t)$ and compute the force at any time along the trajectory.  That gives us a function $\mathbf F(t)$.  In one sense it is an abuse to use the same symbol $\mathbf F$ because one is a function of seven variables and one is a function of one variable.  In another sense it is not an abuse because we are computing the same force in both cases.  The seven dimensional version is much more general.  It can compute the force for any position, velocity, and time.  The one dimensional version can only compute the force for positions along the trajectory at the time when the earth was there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with a World Line from Special Relativity? It represents positions in 4d space. Every point on the line is an "event", just a combination of space and time coordinates.

To picture one, think of the Earth going around the sun. You can think of the Earth as going in a roughly circular path around the sun over time, one cycle per year. The Earth has x,y coordinates in this picture with the sun, roughly in the center.

We can place time on an equal footing with the x and y coordinates by picturing this motion in 3 dimensions. Keep your x y coordinates the same, but imagine an axis of time replace the usual z axis in 3 dimensions. As the earth moves around the sun, it also moves "up" in time, moving towards the future. Graphing time on equal footing with the x,y position, we no longer have a point moving around in a circle, we have an ascending helix.

Geometric features of that helix tell us many things about the motion.

The derivative of x or y with respect to the time, that is, the slope of the tangent line the the helix in the x-t plane, gives information about the velocity of the earth in its orbit. Ditto the y-t plane. The relevant curvatures of the curve give you information about he second derivative, i.e. the Force and Accelerations.

A world line carries all the information about the motion of an object including forces acting upon I think.

So while a Force could be a function of 3 velocity components, 3 position components, and time, it would seem there are necessarily redundancies in $R^7$ that effectively restrict the actual motion to be fully designated in $R^4$. It's sort of like motion on the surface of a globe. That surface can be specified in 3d coordinates and its points in 3D are $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$. But that constraint means there are only actually 2 degrees of freedom making it a 2 dimensional surface.

$m\frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2}=-b\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}-k\vec{x}$

Is a very common equation describing damped harmonic motion. This applies to friction in a vibrating spring, air resistance, to the modified dipole moment of atoms in an applied electric field.  It equates Force with a linear combination of velocity and position, a constraint similar to what applies to the surface of a sphere in 3 dimensions. In this case, the constraints represent physical laws.

Is the surface of a sphere 3D or 2D? In the same sense that that is ambiguous, I think we have that whether a Force is in $R^4$ or $R^7 .$ There are constraints in $R^7$ rendering the behavior observable in $R^4$.